# upgrade to lollipop 5.1 using twrp?

Tags: twrp, 5.1-lollipop

In a burst of energy in the past I installed twrp. But when I attempted to install 5.1 on my nexus 7 2012 by following the prompts, it dumped me into twrp with no information on how to proceed. Do I just hit the install button and find the update in my downloads folder and install that way?

Comment: Don't you need to be on stock recovery to install an OTA update?  I'm pretty sure you do

Comment: Yes, I think that's what the answerer was getting at. That's what I ended up doing, via NRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to flash the rom manually but failed miserably (ran into [this page](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-2012-rooting-roms-hacks/307466-how-recover-nexus-7-2012-bootloader-fail.html)).

I decided to use the Nexus Root Toolkit ([download here](http://www.wugfresh.com/)) to go back to stock Android 5.1 (losing everything on the device of course). That worked like a charm and re-rooting it afterwards was simple enough [Rooting guide for 5.1.1](http://trueandroid.com/how-to-root-nexus-7-2013-wifi-on-official-android-5-1-1-lollipop-lmy48i/).

In the past whenever a new Android version came out I had to flash back to stock Android to get the update and then re-root it. I'm sure some people manage to update without erasing everything...